# Can't get nginx to work on catalina with preinstalled php

Tags: php, nginx, macos-catalina

I just got the new 16inch and it came with os: catalina.

Catalina comes with php7.3 preinstalled, and am also sure it came with php-fpm

```
which php-fpm -> /usr/sbin/php-fpm
```

i installed nginx from homebrew and i can see localhost:8080 working perfectly.
but the problem i have is trying to make a project that works on my ubuntu machine with the below config.

```
server {
 listen 80;
 listen 443;
 server_name wurl.io musicblog.myapps music.ngrok.io;
 root /Users/john-doe/php/projects/musicblog/public;

 add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
 add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
 add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

 index index.html index.htm index.php;

 charset utf-8;
 client_max_body_size 128m;

 location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
 }

 location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
 location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

 error_page 404 /index.php;

 location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
 }

 location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
    deny all;
 }
}
```

when i visit "musicblog.myapps" i get a 502 Bad Gateway.

i am guessing the problem may be this line

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
```

because the path to the .sock does not exists and i can't seem to figure out the path on my macbook.

i also tried this solution recommend by old blog posts

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000
```

but nothing seems to work..

Comment: Maybe this will help you: https://dev.to/chiefoleka/how-to-setup-nginx-and-php71-with-fpm-on-mac-os-x-without-crying-4m8

Comment: @CodyKL I saw that post but it seems Catalina changed alot of things. I followed it but did not work.

Comment: How does your nginx config file looks now? Especially the section for PHP.